# values from different fields in matlab

Tags: math, matlab, field

does anybody familiar with  a way that I could implement a matrix with values from a field (not the real or complex number, but lets say Z mod p). so I could perform all the operation of matlab on the matrix (with the values of the chosen field)
Ariel

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you will want to use Matlab's object-oriented capabilities so that you can define both the fundamental representation of the elements of your field, and the basic operations on them.  There's a reasonably good, if elementary, example of implementing polynomials using Matlab's OO features in the product documentation.  That might be a good place for you to start.